# download image from webpage, without showing webpage to user?

Tags: iphone

is there any method to download image from webpage, without showing webpage to user? 
 one can do this through 'web service'. Is there any other??

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at NSURLConnection.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html

You can also do this in C using CFNetwork.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html